# button auto enable when some item selected in collection view without using ReactiveCocoa framework

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view display some items and a commit button.
I wish the button auto change to enable or disable status depending on whether one or more items are selected on collection view. Like blew picture show

PS: I don't want to use ReactiveCocoa.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is because of cell reuse. You have to set the default values to cell in `cellforrowatindexpath` and then assign the value to controls.

If you are used to make small number of rows then you can `dequeue` cells for every row without reusing the cell. But its not the best practice for large number of rows.

The below code is the best way to reuse cell with identifier

```
SampleViewCell *cell = (SampleViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SampleViewCell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SampleViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }
```